# Yellow Pepper Brown Spots Watery

Tags: food-safety

[image]

Is this pepper safe to eat? Most of it looks fine , just very watery texture.

Answer (score 3):

It's no less safe than any other pepper, unless it's worse than it looks in the photo. Check carefully for signs of mould. The texture will have suffered, so it's probably not great raw,  but I'd cut out the brown bits and cook the rest, and often do, as I buy big cheap bags of peppers and the last couple can hang around for a while.  Most people who grow their own veg would trim and use it without question

Answer (score -1):

This looks like it has begun to spoil and, personally, I would exchange it or get a refund from the store you purchased it at.

When you select your produce: check for firmness and inspect the exterior for any marks (brusing, cuts, etc.). I have found that peppers can seem like they are "broken" from tight packaging or crammed displays. Once that happens, water from the spray water misting systems (that many of our U.S. grocers use) will get inside the product and create the right environment for spoilage.

In summary, IMHO, it would be safer to replace this pepper than to use it.

Comment: Curious... why would this merit a downvote?